# How to replace single quote (') with double quote (") in a file using unix shell script/commands? Apostrophe must not be replaced

Tags: bash, shell, sed, ksh

I'm trying to replace only single quotes (') with double quotes (") in a file in Unix and not the apostrophe ('). Apostrophe (') must remain as is.

I'm getting the desired output with 3 sed commands executed in sequence. However, I'm unable to address the last line 'fake news'.

```
sed -i 's/'\''/"/g' test.txt

sed -i 's/"s/'\''s/g' test.txt

sed -i 's/s"/s'\''/g' test.txt
```

1st sed - converts all single quote to double quote.

2nd sed - converts all double quotes (followed by s) with single quote.

3rd sed - converts all s followed by double quotes with single quote.

Input File -

```
Hello Sir!
How are you?
How's your health?
All 'good'?
Charles' here.
'fake news'
```

Expected Output-

```
Hello Sir!
How are you?
How's your health?
All "good"?
Charles' here.
"fake news"
```

Comment: How do you process `'fake news'`?

Comment: @choroba yes, the 3 sed command that I have written will not be able to handle 'fake news'. I need to address that.

Comment: For any solution, consider how it handles a line like `'Tis good you're thinkin'`. `sed` really isn't up to distinguishing single quotes from apostrophes in general.

Comment: Or even `'Tis good the dogs' toys were found` - completely impossible to distinguish from something like `'The buck stops here' is a quote` with a regexp.

Comment: Use `’` as the apostrophe, not `'`, as is correct typography.

Answer (score 2):

This does what you ask for with a single substitute command:

```
$ sed -E "s/'([^']*)'/\"\1\"/g" file
Hello Sir!
How are you?
How's your health?
All "good"?
Charles' here.
"fake news"
```

The above works by replacing pairs of single quotes with pairs of double quotes.

`'([^']*)'` matches a single-quote followed by any characters other than a single-quote followed by a single-quote.  The characters inside the single-quotes are saved in capture group 1.  The replacement, `\"\1\"`, takes the capture group and puts it inside double-quotes.

While this handles the cases that you asked for, it is easy to imagine more complex cases that couldn't be handled without a sophisticated linguistic analysis.

#### Alternative style

The same command as above can be written in an alternate (but equivalent) shell quoting style:

```
sed -E 's/'\''([^'\'']*)'\''/"\1"/g' file
```

Comment: Alright, that's the winner. I was attempting with `\B` (not word boundary), but ended up with `Charles"`. You got it before I could tease a solution out. Started with `sed -r "s/(\B'|'\B)/\"/g" file` and was trying to work from there...

Comment: This fails for the input in my comment, `'Tis good  you're thinkin'`. It turns it into `"Tis good you"re thinkin'` rather than leaving all three apostrophes untouched.

Comment: Yes, @chepner, while we could work around that example, as my answer stated and your comment implied, there are other cases where we simply couldn't work around it without full linguistic analysis (which is out-of-scope here).

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your three `sed`, you can use a single `perl` regex:

```
perl -p -e 's/([^s])'\''([^s])/$1"$2/g' test.txt
```

**edit: the 'fake news' case**:

You can process half of the 'fake news' case with:

```
perl -p -e 's/([^s]|^)'\''([^s])/$1"$2/g' test.txt
```

To manage the "news'" case, it requires to define the list of words for which the single quote is acceptable (name and surnames). Else, you can add the following process that change the quote after a word that do not start with a capital:

```
perl -p -e 's/([^\w][a-z]+)s'\''/$1s"/g' test.txt
```

In a "single" command (with a pipe):

```
perl -p -e 's/([^s]|^)'\''([^s])/$1"$2/g' test.txt | perl -p -e 's/([^\w][a-z]+)s'\''/$1s"/g'
```

that gives:

> Hello Sir!
>
> How are you?
>
> How's your health?
>
> All "good"?
>
> Charles' here.
>
> "fake news"
>
> a "fake news"

Comment: Or `'s/(?<=[^s])'\''(?=[^s])/"/g'` without capturing.

Comment: This works. But based on @choroba comment on my question, if 'fake news' is written in input file, then this command will not accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can run all the commands in one sed invocation:

```
sed 's/'\''/"/g;s/"s/'\''s/g;s/s"/s'\''/g'
```

or

```
sed -e 's/'\''/"/g' -e 's/"s/'\''s/g' -e 's/s"/s'\''/g'
```

Comment: as you mentioned in comment, the 3 sed command will not be able to address 'fake news'. However, combining and invoking all 3 sed command as one was really helpful. But need to figure out a way to address 'fake news'.